# Issues with Android Browser Default Zoom

Tags: android, css, mobile

I have a site that was built responsive for desktop, and uses media queries to load additional style sheets for various mobile sizes. I have a style sheet built for iPad that loads between 768px and 1024px wide, and that works perfectly, as well I have a sheet that loads between 320px and 480px for iPhone and this is just fine as well. I have a third sheet that loads inbetween those two for Android, and this is where my trouble lies. After a few adjustments I have it loading almost perfectly on Android with the exception that it is too zoomed in. Zooming out gives you the expected view, however adjusting things like zoom and pixel density via meta tags are of no use and often cause more trouble.

What is going on??

Comment: Does this not all depend on the resolution of the Android device? Try on a different device and see if it is similar

Comment: I've tried it on a few Android devices, a Galaxy, a Galaxy tab, as well a co-worker has tried with similar results on his set of droids. At first I thought it was a max-width issue and the page was just loading that way but it doesn't seem to be the case anymore.